# Does PostgreSQL 12.x have any built-in abilities to "predict future numbers"?

Tags: postgresql

I know of third-party extensions for this. I'm not interested in those. I find dealing with extensions and extra software to be a nightmare. I need for it to be built in.

I'm basically trying to predict the next, or many future numbers, based on the existing integer or datetime data in a column in a table.

Basically, I want to do:

```
SELECT next_predicted(sold_at) FROM car_sales BASED ON sold_at > now() - INTERVAL '1 year' LIMIT 1;
```

Or:

```
SELECT next_predicted(weight) FROM my_weight BASED ON measured_at > now() - INTERVAL '3 months' LIMIT 1;
```

It doesn't need to feature the best AI in existence. I don't expect the PostgreSQL developers to agree to compensate me monetarily if these "predicted" numbers/timestamps turn out to be horribly wrong. I will not sue anyone. I do not expect it to be perfect, or even anywhere near perfect.

I expect to use it mostly as a novelty. If I decide to bet my kids' college funds on the next number being what PG predicts, and it turns out to be wrong, I will have only my own naivety to blame. The documentation can have a big disclaimer or something to make this clear to anyone who doesn't already have my mindset.

It can even be based on some very crude and basic math calculation, simply determining the "average" of the existing data or something, just without me having to think about this and create a manual query for it.

Is there such a thing? If not, is one planned?

Answer (score 1):

You can only predict a future value if you have a theory of how of the values develop.

Lacking that, you might as well guess the previous value:

```
lag(weight) OVER (ORDER BY measure_time)
```

or assume a linear progression:

```
2 * weight - lag(weight) OVER (ORDER BY measure_time)
```